# Slope Intercept Formula for Finding list of y values

Tags: python, list, data-fitting

I am running into this error when I run my code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    y[i] = m*i + b
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I am trying to determine what I am doing wrong. This is my code.

```
m = 5
b = 10

y = []

for i in range(0,20):
    y[i] = m*i + b
    y.append(y)
```

I want to append all the values from 0 to 20 into a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not assign to a `list` element that does not already exist. Instead simply append the result to `y` like:

```
y = []
for i in range(0, 20):
    y.append(m * i + b)
```

or as a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
y = [m * i + b for i in range(0, 20)]
```